# Change Contact Selector display name?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, display-name

Is there a way to change the way a DisplayName is shown in infopath 2010? I have a contact selector and when the DisplayName is shown, its the Last Name, First Name. Can I have it show as First Name, Last Name in a field?

Answer (score 1):

yes... you can write the value as "Concat(firstName,' ', lastName )"